# Passing an argument to a class method

Tags: python

I am trying to get to grips with working with objects in python and have encountered an error which is confusing me. I have added the following property to a class:

```
@property
def train(self, index):
  return self.make_dataset(self.train_df[index])
```

I want to pass it the argument 'index' so that I can call this function during a training loop. However when I try this with the following code, I get the error:

```
train() missing 1 required positional argument: 'index'
```

Even though I did pass the argument as below. I have been looking on the internet but still can't work out what the route cause of the warning is. Is this an incorrect way to mass an argument to a method?

```
for train_loop in range(len(train_df)):
    history = model.fit(multi_window.train(train_loop))
```

Comment: `train` should be an ordinary method, not a property.

Comment: why are you making this a property instead of a regular method?

Comment: A property is not a regular class method. If you want to ask about properties, your question title should reflect that. If you want to ask about class methods, your question's body should actually be _about regular class methods_, not about properties. (`@classmethod`, not `@property`).

Answer (score 1):

Remove the @property decorator:

```
def train(self, index):
    return self.make_dataset(self.train_df[index])
```

This will make it an instance method, callable by an object of the class (if that's what you'd like it to be).